List all privileges a user has for a specific table (DB2 AS400)
Using a db2 database hosted on an IBM AS400 Version:V5R4M0 I'm having trouble trying to list permissions a user has on a specific table.
Here IBM lists different ways to do so, but I get a file not found error when using the different examples. Using System i Navigator I do not even see a SYSCAT schema. Browsing the Navigator, the closest I was able to find is a view in SYSIBM called  SQLTABLEPRIVILEGES
When I query this view on a specific user, it's only showing for two tables, when the user has privileges on many other tables.
Many solutions I come across do not seem to work because of how old the version being used is and the libraries/tables/views don't exist.
We're transitions legacy RPG applications, and I only know enough to get around the system as needed, and my primary role is a .NET developer.  So any help would be appreciated.

Just so you know, the docs you linked were DB2 for LUW which is somewhat different from DB2 for i. The documentation for DB2 for i is here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=views-i-catalog-tables Beware! this is for v7.1, you are using v5.4 which is quite old, and IBM no longer has documentation available online for this old version. Some stuff that is available for v7.1, will not work for v5.4.

@jmarkmurphy Thank you! def will be useful to have for future reference.

Where you got only 2 objects back for the user, try,
Maybe the user in a group? Use the DSPUSRPRF command from the AS400 command line to find out. Then you can look for the priviliges for the group which the user will have.
If you look for priviliges for the *PUBLIC user? All users will have access to those objects.
ASIDE:
to look at the authorities an object has,
dspobjaut lib/obj *type
eg. dspobjaut libname/filename *file
(typing dspobjaut (or any command) at the AS400 command line and then pressing F4 shows the commands parameters. Then F1 anywhere on screen gives you help on the heading and params)
(typing
go cmd
followed by part of a command gives help
eg.
go cmdaut
in this case
)
UPDATE:
Re. finding out if the user is in a group, this works on my AS400 but it is at release V7R4M0
SELECT GROUP_PROFILE_NAME FROM qsys2.USER_INFO

Appreciate the help! I didn't have a chance to update the answer but I was able to determine the other tables the user had access were set to Public.   Running SQLTABLEPRIVILEGES on some of the tables in question I was able to verify that rather than just searching on the user.  So  SQLTABLEPRIVILEGES in this instance actually was giving me all the information I needed, I was just going in the wrong direction.  SQLTABLEPRIVILEGES does take a long time to return results though. Took about 20 min or so each time I used it!
